# Gmaps can't display map - jupyter-gmaps' is loaded but can not be instantiated

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

Using the gmaps starter example:

```
import os
import requests
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets

gmaps.configure(api_key="API KEY HERE")

earthquake_df = gmaps.datasets.load_dataset_as_df('earthquakes')
earthquake_df.head()

locations = earthquake_df[['latitude', 'longitude']]
weights = earthquake_df['magnitude']
fig = gmaps.figure()
fig.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer(locations, weights=weights))
fig
```

I have followed all the setup instructions from gmaps and nbextensions etc - everything enabled, but when I run I get this error and cannot display the map (the dataset table displays fine):

**Model class 'FigureModel' from module 'jupyter-gmaps' is loaded but can not be instantiated**

I can see in the console this error too: [Error] Refused to execute http://localhost:8888/nbextensions/gmaps.js?v=20230810111648 as script because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.

Have searched and searched and tried everything but still facing this error

Comment: Hello! I tried your code on my end, but it seems to be working fine. Did you put a valid or working API key in your code?

Comment: I downgraded notebook versions and it seems to work fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded to Jupyter notebook 5.7.5 and it worked!

Comment: can you please run `jupyter --version` and share the output? I'm getting the same error with the following versions:


`Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.4.0
ipykernel        : 6.13.0
ipywidgets       : 8.0.6
jupyter_client   : 8.3.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.1
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : 7.7.4
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : 5.7.5
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.9.0`

Comment: I am having the same issue, I downgraded to notebook 5.7.5 but still not able to instantiate the gmaps

Comment: edit: So the ipywidgets is the one having the problem. Downgrading it to 7.6.5 worked for me