# gmaps Model class 'FigureModel' from module 'jupyter-gmaps' is loaded but can not be instantiated

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter-notebook

The following code in Jupyter notebook:

```
import gmaps
gmaps.configure(api_key="AI...")

layout={'width': '1000px', 'height': '900px'}
fig = gmaps.figure(layout=layout)
fig
```

Raises the following error:

```
Model class 'FigureModel' from module 'jupyter-gmaps' is loaded but can not be instantiated
TypeError: Class constructor L cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new t (http://localhost:8888/nbextensions/jupyter-gmaps/index.js?v=20230818125827:39:179771)
    at u._make_model (http://localhost:8888/nbextensions/jupyter-js-widgets/extension.js?v=20230818125827:2:752664)
```

Jupyter versions:

```
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.4.0
ipykernel        : 6.13.0
ipywidgets       : 8.0.6
jupyter_client   : 8.3.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.1
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : 7.7.4
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : 5.7.5
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.9.0
```

Comment: This looks similar to a question previously asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76874891/18422887 Have you tried downgrading?